# R: Extract and "cut" the extracted part from the original data

Tags: r, subset

I have a set of data like this:

```
id ---- name ---- beg_date ---- end_date --- type_1 --- type_2 ... type_n
01 ---- xxxx ---- 2015-10  ---- 2015-11  ----- Y -------- Y -------- N---
01 ---- xxxx ---- 2014-03  ---- 2015-09  ----- N -------- Y -------- N---
```

etc.

I want to make a table to count how many items of each type available for each month, so I wil do a loop from each the smallest oldest date to the most recent date by month.
In each iteration, I will extract all rows that have the beg_date <= the date of the iteration and  end_date > the date of the iteration.
I will count how many rows of this subset belongs to type 1, type 2, ...
After I've done, I don't need this subset of data, so I want to remove it to speed up the next iteration.

Do you know how to subset and also "cut" the part from the original data?
Thanks very much.

Comment: Instead of explaining the algorithm, the code would be easier to understand. Still, you can use basic subsetting tools to remove some rows, like `df <- df[-10:20,]`. There may be better ways of doing what you want though.